# How to update to latest OpenGL version on Virtualbox Ubuntu Linux machine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, intel-graphics, opengl

I'm running **Ubuntu 16.10** on **VirtualBox** version **5.1.10** with installed latest guest additions. My host system is **Ubuntu 14.04** with graphics adapter:

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)

According its [specifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_graphics_processing_units#Ninth_generation) it supports **OpenGL** up to version **4.5** on *Linux*. My guest system graphics adapter is shown as:

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter

According to **glxinfo** my current **OpenGL** version on guest system is:

```
> glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Humper
OpenGL renderer string: Chromium
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Chromium 1.9
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL extensions:
```

How to upgrade graphics driver on guest system to newest **OpenGL** version possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't, at least with VirtualBox.

According to the manual (link below), only OpenGL 2 is supported through the VirtualBox virtual graphics adapter. It seems that the supported version is actually now 2.1, but I can't find a reference to anything more recent than that.

> [20] OpenGL support for Windows guests was added with VirtualBox 2.1;
>   support for Linux and Solaris followed with VirtualBox 2.2. With
>   VirtualBox 3.0, Direct3D 8/9 support was added for Windows guests.
>   OpenGL 2.0 is now supported as well. With VirtualBox 4.1 Windows Aero
>   theme support is added for Windows Vista and Windows 7 guests
>   (experimental)

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html